# ReactJs filter returns an object

Tags: reactjs, filter

I am trying to create a filter feature in my Reactjs app (which also includes some Redux). I am a newbie so I'm still trying to get the hang of ReactJs.I want to be able to search through my list of matters, return either the original list, or the resulted search. My matter list is inside my MattersContainer.js.

In my app, I have my SearchBar.js as child component of App.js.

```
class App extends React.Component {

  state = {
      filteredMatter: [],   
  }

  componentDidMount() {
      this.props.fetchMatters();   
  }

  onSearchSubmit = (searchTerm) => {    
      const filterResults = this.props.matters.filter(matter => matter.case_title.toLowerCase()
=== searchTerm.toLowerCase())   
      this.setState({filteredMatter: filterResults})           
  }

  render() {  
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Router>      
            <NavBar />
            <SearchBar onSubmit={this.onSearchSubmit}/>            
            <Sidebar />
            <Switch>
              <div className="matters-container">
                <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
                <Route exact path="/matters">
                  <MattersContainer matters={this.state.filteredMatter.length > 0 ? this.state.filteredMatter : this.props.matters}/>
                </Route>
                <Route exact path="/matters/new" render={(routerProps) => <MatterForm {...routerProps} />} />
                <Route exact path="/matters/:id" render={(routerProps) => {
                  const matterId = parseInt(routerProps.match.params.id)
                  // debugger
                  const matterObj = this.props.matters.find(matterArrObj => matterArrObj.id === matterId)
                  
                  if (matterObj) {
                    return (
                      <Matter key={matterObj.id}
                              matters={matterObj}
                              {...routerProps}
                      />
                      )
                  } 
                }
                }/>
                <Route path='/tasks' component={TasksContainer} />
              </div> 
                  
            </Switch>
        </Router>
      </React.Fragment>
    )   } }

const mapStateToProps = state => {   
    return ({
        matters: state.matterReducer.matters   
    }) 
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {fetchMatters})(App)`
```

**>     My SearchBar.js looks like this:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export default class SearchBar extends Component {

    constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = {
            searchTerm: ''
        }
    }

    onInputChange = (event) => {
        this.setState({
            searchTerm: event.target.value
        })
    }

    onFormSubmit = (event) => {
        debugger
        event.preventDefault();
        this.props.onSubmit(this.state.searchTerm)
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <form onSubmit={this.onFormSubmit}>
                    <input 
                        type="text" 
                        value={this.state.searchTerm}
                        onChange={this.onInputChange} 
                    />
                    <button type="Submit">Search for a matter</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

**This is my MattersContainer:**

```
class MattersContainer extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <>
      <div className="matter" >
        <h3>Your Matters</h3>   
        <Paper style={{ overflow:'hidden',margin: '5px', display: 'flex',justifyContent: 'space-between' }}>
        <Table>
          <TableHead>
            <TableRow>
              <TableCell>Matter</TableCell>
              <TableCell>Client</TableCell>
            </TableRow>
          </TableHead>
          <TableBody>
          {this.props.mattersArr.map(matter => (
              <TableRow key={matter.id} >
                <TableCell>
                    <Link to={`/matters/${matter.id}`}>{matter.case_title} </Link>              

                </TableCell>
                <TableCell>
                    {matter.client}
                </TableCell>
              </TableRow>
          ))}
          </TableBody>
        </Table>   
        </Paper>
        
      </div>
      </>
    )
  }
}

const mSTP = state => {
  return {mattersArr: state.matterReducer.matters};
}

const mDTP = dispatch => ({
  deleteMatter: id => dispatch({type: "DELETE_MATTER", id})
});

export default connect(mSTP, mDTP)(MattersContainer);
```

Comment: Do you receive any error.

Comment: What filter is returning an object? `Array.prototype.filter` returns only new array.

Comment: You are passing a prop `matters` to `MattersContainer` but *not* using it inside MattersContainer but using a prop which comes through the redux i.e. `mattersArr`. It is not clear what you are trying to do and what's the issue. Please edit your question to improve it. Or maybe you are trying to show filtered data in this component, So, you should use `this.props.matters` not `this.props.mattersArr`.

Comment: I'm not getting any errors. I see the object that I am trying to get, but it just isn't showing up in my matterscontainer. `{id: 4, case_title: "BBB vs. STE", lead_attorney: "Mary J", associate_attorney: "Katrina T.", client: "Safca", …}` is the result of when I `console.log(matter)` in my onSearchSubmit function.

Comment: When I console log my updated filteredMatter state after setting the new state    (`console.log(this.state.filteredMatter)`), it returns an empty array. Anyone know why?

Comment: Where do you see the object you are trying to get? What is `matter`, the one from the filter callback? Your `this.state.filteredMatter` local component state from `App` isn't the same `state.matterReducer.matters` from your redux state. Where are you console logging `this.state.filteredMatter`?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use Redux to dispatch state, you must be initing state searchTemp in App.js

```
this.state = {
 searchTemp: null,
}
```

After that you create functions set state searchTemp:

```
const setSearchTemp =(searchKey)=>{
 this.setState({ searchTemp: searchKey });
}
```

And send functions setSearchTemp to component SearchBar to get keyword filter